# CodeIgniter code being commented out by HTML

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.4 with PHP 5.5.12 on my local machine.

My PHP code seems to be commented out in HTML automatically.

Below is a snippet of my code:-

```
<? if($this->agent->browser()=='MSIE'){ ?>
    <img class="bg" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/img/bg.jpg" alt="Login Background" />
<? } ?>
```

When I try to inspect it in Chrome, it shows the below:-

```
<!--? if($this--->
agent-&gt;browser()=='MSIE'){ ?&gt;
<img class="bg" src="http://localhost/abc/assets/img/bg.jpg" alt="Login Background">
<!--? } ?-->
```

This is just one of a few places that was automatically commented out. I know the code works because I have the same code working well on a production server. It is just happening on my local machine.

Comment: I am not sure, but try replace `<?` with `<?php`. Maybe it won't help, but it worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use long open tags.

```
<?php if($this->agent->browser()=='MSIE'){ ?>
```

Or if for some reason cannot do that then enable [short-open-tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) setting.

Comment: I think you meant **enable** short-open-tag. That solved the problem indeed. Thank you so much!